# Docker: Permission denied on folders added with ADD

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions, docker

I'm trying to configure a postgresql installation using docker.

```
FROM ubuntu:13.10

ADD . /db

# install postgres
# ...

RUN chown postgres:postgres /db -R && \
    chmod 700 /db -R

USER postgres
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    createdb test &&\
    psql -d test -f /db/all.sql
```

I can access to the folder /db, but not to /db/plpgsql (which contains files executed by /db/all.sql)

I tried chmod 777 on /db/plpgsql but it does not work either, permission is denied.

```
postgres@c364bdd94652:/$ ls -l | grep db
drwxrwxrwx   5 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 10 17:39 db
postgres@c364bdd94652:/$ cd db/
postgres@c364bdd94652:/db$ ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   2567 Jul 10 16:34 Dockerfile
-rwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    358 Jul 10 14:53 all.sql
-rwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    642 Jul 10 15:35 init.sql
drwxrwxrwx 10 postgres postgres   4096 Jul 10 16:36 plpgsql
postgres@c364bdd94652:/db$ cd plpgsql/
bash: cd: plpgsql/: Permission denied
```

How do I access to that folder ?

Comment: Might be selinux permissions need to be applied.  If that is the case, running ls -Z should let you see it at least:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-selinux-security-context-using-ls/

Comment: I reported an issue on the docker repo at https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6972, which has more or less been adressed by this pull request: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9467

Comment: Oh my.  That possibility did not occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

While there was some resolution in the [commented issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6972), it seems like this may be related to [a problem with AUFS](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/783).

If your `docker info` reports your aufs driver is missing dirperm1 support:

```
Storage Driver: aufs
  Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs 
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Dirs: 148
  Dirperm1 Supported: false
```

...then you might need to update the aufs on your host, or try using a different storage driver. Somewhat frustrating to run into this with aufs as the default storage driver, when changing permissions is something you'd just kind of expect to work correctly.